Shopware administration save custom field while creating new order
I have created a custom field called OrderType, now my task is to submit the selected order type to the database while creating an order in shopware administration panel.
How can I do it?
I have tried with setting the selectedCustomField to the Context but it did not saved.
I have no idea how can I pull order object and add my custom field before saving it to database.
My new component:
Component.override('sw-order-create-options', {
    template,

    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory',
        'acl',
        'customFieldDataProviderService',
        'feature',
    ],

    props: {
        context: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            customFieldSets: null,
            selectedCustomField: null,
        };
    },

    computed: {
        orderRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('order');
        },
        customFieldSetRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('custom_field');
        },
        customFieldSetCriteria() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            console.log(this.context)

            criteria.addFilter(Criteria.equals('name', 'order_custom_field_order_type'));

            return criteria;
        },
        customFieldOptions() {
            if (!this.customFieldSets) {
                return [];
            }
            const fieldSet = this.customFieldSets[0]; // Assuming only one set is fetched
            return fieldSet.config.options.map(option => ({
                value: option.value,
                label: option.label
            }));
        }
    },

    watch: {
        context: {
            handler(newVal) {
                console.log('Context changed:', newVal);
            },
            deep: true,
        },
        selectedCustomField(newVal) {
            console.log('Selected Custom Field:', newVal);
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        createdComponent() {
            this.loadCustomFieldSets();
        },

        loadCustomFieldSets() {
            this.customFieldSetRepository.search(this.customFieldSetCriteria, Shopware.Context.api)
                .then((customFieldSets) => {
                    this.customFieldSets = customFieldSets;
                });
        },
    },
});

and twig js file:
{% block sw_order_create_options_order %}
    <sw-single-select
            v-if="customFieldSets"
            :options="customFieldOptions"
            v-model:value="selectedCustomField"
            label="Select Custom Field"
            placeholder="Please select an orderType"
    />

{% endblock %}
 

